# KeyVault integration - [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

I have been trying to write some basic code to test out Azure KeyVault.  At the moment (as you can see from the console log), I can authenticate but *KeyVaultClient* just fails with a *[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file*.

There seems to be a bit of a lack of real-world examples from Microsoft in relation to the azure-java-sdk, so I admit I have been struggling a bit doing my best interpreting the JavaDocs !

> 16:12:02.391 [main] DEBUG com.example.cli.Main - Launched !
>   16:12:02.453 [main] DEBUG e.s.cli.AzureAuthenticationResult -
>   Authresult getToken
>
> 16:12:02.491 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG
>   c.m.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext - [Correlation ID:
>   XXXXXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX] Using Client Http Headers:
>   x-client-SKU=java;x-client-VER=1.0.0;x-client-OS=XXXX;x-client-CPU=XXXX;return-client-request-id=true;client-request-id=XXXXXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX;
>
> 16:12:02.491 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO 
>   c.m.a.adal4j.AuthenticationAuthority - [Correlation ID:
>   XXXXXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX] Instance discovery was successful
>
> 16:12:05.142 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG
>   c.m.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext - [Correlation ID:
>   XXXXXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX] Access Token with hash
>   'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' returned
>
> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end
>   of file.
>
> 16:12:08.135 [main] ERROR com.example.cli.Main - null
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>
> at
>   com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:53)
>   ~[azure-keyvault-0.9.0.jar:na]
>   at
>   com.example.cli.Main.main(Main.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>   at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   [idea_rt.jar:na]
>
> Caused by:
>   com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException:
>   at >com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException.createFromXml(ServiceException.java:216)
>   ~[azure-core-0.9.0.jar:na]
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyOperationsImpl.sign(KeyOperationsImpl.java:1524)
>   ~[azure-keyvault-0.9.0.jar:na]
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyOperationsImpl$13.call(KeyOperationsImpl.java:1447)
>   ~[azure-keyvault-0.9.0.jar:na]
>     at >com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyOperationsImpl$13.call(KeyOperationsImpl.java:1444)
>   ~[azure-keyvault-0.9.0.jar:na]
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

```
package com.example.cli;

import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClientService;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.models.KeyOperationResult;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.webkey.JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import java.security.*;

import java.util.Random;

import java.util.concurrent.Future;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
        logger.debug("Launched !");

        try {
            byte[] plainText = new byte[100];
            new Random(0x1234567L).nextBytes(plainText);
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(plainText);
            byte[] digest = md.digest();
            Configuration configuration = AzureKVCredentials.createConfiguration();
            KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = KeyVaultClientService.create(configuration);
            Future<KeyOperationResult> keyOperationPromise;
            KeyOperationResult keyOperationResult;
            keyOperationPromise = keyVaultClient.signAsync("https://XXXXXXX.vault.azure.net/keys/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXX”,JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm.RS256,digest);
            keyOperationResult = keyOperationPromise.get();   // <=== THIS IS LINE 37 IN THE STACKTRACE   ;-)   <====
            byte[] res = keyOperationResult.getResult();
            String  b64 = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(res);
            logger.debug(b64);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(null,e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try to use Azure REST API to manage Key Vault? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt620024.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using Azure KeyVault, you can try to use Azure REST APIs to manage and operate the Key Vault. Please refer to the Key Vault REST document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn903630.aspx.

There are two set of APIs for Key Vault management and Keys & Secrets operations that need different access tokens from different resource uri.

For management apis, the resource uri is `https://management.core.windows.net/`.

For operation apis, the resource uri is `https://vault.azure.net`. (*Note: Please notice there is no symbol `/` at the end of the uri.* )

Here is a sample code as references.

```
package aad.keyvault;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;

public class RestAPISample {

    private static final String subscriptionId = "<subscription_id>";
    private static final String resourceGroupName = "<resource_group_name>";
    private static final String vaultName = "<vault_name>";
    private static final String apiVersion = "2015-06-01";
    private static final String getKeyVaultInfoUri = String.format(
            "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%s/resourceGroups/%s/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/%s?api-version=%s",
            subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, vaultName, apiVersion);

    private static final String tenantId = "<tenant_id>";
    private static final String authority = String.format("https://login.windows.net/%s", tenantId);
    private static final String clientId = "<client_id>";
    private static final String clientSecret = "<client_secret_key>";
    private static final String keyName = "<keyvault_key>";
    private static final String getInfoFromAKeyUri = String.format("https://%s.vault.azure.net/keys/%s?api-version=%s",
            vaultName, keyName, apiVersion);

    public static String getAccessToken(String resource)
            throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException, ServiceUnavailableException {
        AuthenticationContext context = null;
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true, service);
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(resource, credential, null);
            result = future.get();
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }
        String accessToken = null;
        if (result == null) {
            throw new ServiceUnavailableException("authentication result was null");
        } else {
            accessToken = result.getAccessToken();
            System.out.println("Access Token: " + accessToken);
        }
        return accessToken;
    }

    public static void getKeyVaultInfo() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceUnavailableException,
            InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println(getKeyVaultInfoUri);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(getKeyVaultInfoUri).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessToken("https://management.core.windows.net/"));
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        String resp = IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(resp);
    }

    public static void getKeyInfo() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceUnavailableException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println(getInfoFromAKeyUri);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(getInfoFromAKeyUri).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessToken("https://vault.azure.net"));
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        String resp = IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(resp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, ServiceUnavailableException, IOException {
        getKeyVaultInfo();
        getKeyInfo();
    }

}
```

Azure Key Vault operation APIs need different permissions setted by using command `set-policy`. For example `Get information about a key`(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn878080.aspx), it need authorization requires the keys/get permission by using Azure CLI cmd `azure keyvault set-policy --vault-name <vault-name> --spn <service-principal-no.> --perms-to-keys '["get"]'` to add permission `get` to keys.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, so I suspect your credentials object (which you didn't provide) is not valid. In special, make sure you use a `KeyVaultConfiguration` instance.

Here's my working version of your `AzureKVCredentials`:

```
package com.example.cli;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.message.*;

import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.authentication.*;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.*;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.pipeline.filter.*;

public class AzureKVCredentials extends KeyVaultCredentials {

    public static Configuration createConfiguration() {
        return KeyVaultConfiguration.configure(null, new AzureKVCredentials()); 
    }

    @Override
    public Header doAuthenticate(ServiceRequestContext request, Map<String, String> challenge) {
        try {
            String authorization = challenge.get("authorization");
            String resource = challenge.get("resource");
            AuthenticationResult authResult = getAccessToken(authorization, resource);
            return new BasicHeader("Authorization", authResult.getAccessTokenType() + " " + authResult.getAccessToken());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static AuthenticationResult getAccessToken(String authorization, String resource) throws Exception {

        String clientId = "<app id of your Azure application>";
        String clientKey = "<application key>";

        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authorization, false, service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = null;
            ClientCredential credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientKey);
            future = context.acquireToken(resource, credentials, null);
            result = future.get();
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }
        if (result == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("authentication result was null");
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

This code is based on [these sources](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/services/keyvault/azure-keyvault/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/keyvault/test/KeyVaultClientIntegrationTestBase.java#L107) from the azure-sdk-for-java.